# Adsense ads sometimes not centered and/or appearing in weird places

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, adsense, absolute

This seems like a relatively straightforward question, but I haven't been able to find any working answers. Frequently (but not always), when Google serves ads to my pages, they appear off-center, or totally outside of the parent div. I get that this has to do with the absolute positioning of the ads inside the divs, and I've tried monkeying around with the CSS--including in the Google ad code under the `style` attribute--but to no avail.

I'm not using auto ads, and have changed the `data-ad-format` fields to "horizontal" (1st picture) and "rectangle" (2nd picture). I've also changed the `data-full-width-responsive` field to "false".

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- ad header -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-9877834918277834"
     data-ad-slot="1366524238"
     data-ad-format="auto"
     data-full-width-responsive="false"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

The CSS of the divs housing the ads is as follows:

```
.ad-slot {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; /* Otherwise be outside the div */
  text-align: center; /* Doesn't seem to do anything */
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an iframe styling issue. I was hacking around with some JS and accidentally ended up styling all iframes on the page (including the ads).